# Properly Getting Firebase Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on an app for a club where members attendance should be recorded. I'm having trouble getting it properly in a list view.

Here is a portion of the database:

[image]

There might be more than one sport attended like Karate or swimming for a given day. I want to get the member's attendance in a list view. I'll try to section it by day later, but for now I need to get the data properly.
Here is the model I made:

```
public class MemberAttendance {

private String day;
private HashMap<String, Object> attendedSport;


public MemberAttendance() {

}

public MemberAttendance(String day, HashMap<String, Object> attendedSport) {

    this.day = day;
    this.attendedSport = attendedSport;

}

public String getDay() {
    return day;
}

public void setDay(String day) {
    this.day = day;
}

public HashMap<String, Object> getAttendedSport() {
    return attendedSport;
}

public void setAttendedSport(HashMap<String, Object> attendedSport) {
    this.attendedSport = attendedSport;
}
```

}

Here is the adapter:

```
public class MemberAttendanceAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<MemberAttendance> {

public MemberAttendanceAdapter(Activity activity, Class<MemberAttendance> modelClass, int modelLayout, Query ref) {
    super(activity, modelClass, modelLayout, ref);
}

@Override
protected void populateView(View view, MemberAttendance memberAttendance, int i) {

    // Get values from firebase database
    String day = memberAttendance.getDay();

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = memberAttendance.getAttendedSport();
    String sport = (String) hashMap.get("attended");
    String date = (String) hashMap.get("timestamp");

    // Create views and assign values
    TextView dayTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dayTxtView);
    dayTxtView.setText(day);

    TextView sportTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sportTxtView);
    sportTxtView.setText(sport);

    TextView dateTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTxtView);
    dateTxtView.setText(date);

}
```

}

And here how I try to set the adapter:

```
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    final DatabaseReference attendanceRef = database.getReference()
           .child(Constants.MEMBERS_NODE).child(userID).child("attendance");

    attendanceAdapter = new MemberAttendanceAdapter(getActivity(), MemberAttendance.class,
            R.layout.attendance_list_item, attendanceRef);

    attendanceListView.setAdapter(attendanceAdapter);
```

So far not working and gives null pointer exception on the object reference that uses HashMap.get(..)

```
String sport = (String) hashMap.get("attended");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The getAttendedSport HashMap is trying to get a node called "attendedSport", but there is no node called "attendedSport" instead it just looks like a random id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to restructure your NoSQL Database like this:

```
member
---memberID
------attendance
---------attendance ID
------------attended
------------timestamp
------------date
```

For example:

```
member
---member1
------attendance
---------attendance1
------------soccer
------------14938372834
------------14-04-2017
---------attendance2
------------swimming
------------14938374323
------------14-04-2017
```

You don't need to store the date because use could use the timestamp to create a Date object in Java that would contain that information

```
Date date = new Date(timestamp);
```

With this structure you would need to change your POJO to this:

```
public class MemberAttendance {

    private String attended;
    private long timestamp;


    public MemberAttendance() {

    }

    public MemberAttendance(String attended, long timestamp) {

        this.attended = attended;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;

    }

    public String getAttended() {
        return attended;
    }

    public void setAttended(String attended) {
        this.attended = attended;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.attendedSport = attendedSport;
    } 
}
```

And then you could use your same Firebase Query with the following changes in the adapter:

```
public class MemberAttendanceAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<MemberAttendance> {

    public MemberAttendanceAdapter(Activity activity, Class<MemberAttendance> modelClass, int modelLayout, Query ref) {
        super(activity, modelClass, modelLayout, ref);
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, MemberAttendance memberAttendance, int i) {

        String sport = memberAttendace.getAttended();
        Date date = new Date(memberAttendance.getTimestamp());

        // Create views and assign values
        TextView dayTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dayTxtView);
        dayTxtView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(date););

        TextView sportTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sportTxtView);
        sportTxtView.setText(sport);

        //I think you want to show the time here, not the date
        TextView dateTxtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTxtView);
        dateTxtView.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(date));

    }
}
```

---

Edit: As for your comment in querying the attendances by date, check the edits I made in the structure above and then use a Firebase Query like

```
ref.child("members")
   .child(<memberIdHere>)
   .child("attendance")
   .orderByChild("date")
   .equalTo(<yourDateHere>);
```

Comment: That was a correct way to do it, thank you. Can you think of a way so that I can combine attendances belonging to the same day in a single list item?

Comment: If you want to query them by date, you could use a Firebase Query where their dates are equalTo a specific date. I've edited my answer for this. I modified the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `HashMap` I would recommended to create another object like `AttendedSport` as variable inside `MemberAttendance` then `Firebase` will map the data for with out using `HashMap` inside `populateView` you could get data like

`memberAttendance.getAttendedSport().getSport()` and `memberAttendance.getAttendedSport().getTimeStamp()`

I'm not guarantee it would fix your problem but I think it is less error prone.